# Reading solar inverter data using esp32 and rs232 to ttl

Tags: serial-port, esp32, modbus

I am trying to read Inverter data using esp32 and RS232 to TTL converter.
[image: RS232 to TTL]

The documentation suggest the request to be as follows
[image: Request snap from documents]

The documentation response is as follows
[image: Response snap from documents]

The code I had written to read register 150 is as follows:

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

HardwareSerial SerialRS232(2);  // RS232 is connected to UART2 on ESP32
#define RS232_BAUDRATE 9600    // RS232 baudrate

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);       // Serial Monitor baudrate
  SerialRS232.begin(RS232_BAUDRATE);
}

void loop() {
  uint8_t request[] = {0x03, 0x00, 0x96, 0x00, 0x03};  // Request to read 3 consecutive registers starting at address 150
  SerialRS232.write(request, sizeof(request));        // Send the request to the inverter
  delay(100);                                          // Wait for the response

  if (SerialRS232.available() >= 8) {                  // Check if the response is available
    uint8_t response[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      response[i] = SerialRS232.read();                // Read the response into an array
    }

    if (response[0] == 0x03 && response[1] == 0x06) {  // Check if the response is valid
      uint16_t register1 = (response[2] << 8) | response[3];  // Combine the high and low bytes of the first register
      uint16_t register2 = (response[4] << 8) | response[5];  // Combine the high and low bytes of the second register
      uint16_t register3 = (response[6] << 8) | response[7];  // Combine the high and low bytes of the third register

      float voltage1 = register1 * 0.1;                // Calculate the voltage of the first register
      float voltage2 = register2 * 0.1;                // Calculate the voltage of the second register
      float voltage3 = register3 * 0.1;                // Calculate the voltage of the third register

      Serial.print("Grid side voltage L1-N: ");
      Serial.print(voltage1);
      Serial.print(" V, ");
      Serial.print(voltage2);
      Serial.print(" V, ");
      Serial.print(voltage3);
      Serial.println(" V");
    }
  }
}
```

But I am not getting any value. Kindly suggest what am I doing Wrong

While sending the request I am expecting Voltage value but I am getting nothing.

Comment: Before you can debug your code, you first have to debug your hardware. What kind of connection do you have between your "*solar inverter*" and "*RS232 to TTL converter*"? How have you connected the four pins of your "*RS232 to TTL converter*" to the ESP32? Have you used an oscilloscope to verify the signals?

Comment: So, the connections are as follows:    MAX3232 TX ---> ESP32 16         MAX3232 RX ---> ESP32 17            MAX3232 VCC ---> ESP32 3.3V       MAX3232 GND---> ESP32 GND.         No, I haven't used an oscilloscope to verify signals.

Comment: Please also tell us which inverter you are attempting to communicate with. My guess is that [the docs](https://forum.iobroker.net/assets/uploads/files/1647537097588-sunsynk_modbus.pdf) are only showing the Modbus protocol data unit (PDU) so when sending an actual request you need to add the Address field and CRC (assuming this is a Modbus RTU unit; which it appears to be if I found the right docs).

Comment: "*So, the connections are as follows: MAX3232 TX ---> ESP32 16 ...*" -- You only responded to 2 of the three questions. FYI you cannot blindly rely on the pin labels. You need to verify signal direction of each pin. I have an identical "*RS232 to TTL converter*" as your photo. The pin labeled `TXD` is an input (connected to pin 11 of the MAX3232 IC), and the `RXD` is an output (connected to pin 12 of the MAX3232 IC). So your "*RS232 to TTL converter*" connection to the ESP32 is nonfunctional. You have an input connected to another input, and an output connected to another output.

Comment: @Brits I am using an inverex inverter and documents does not had anymore info than that. Nothing is mentioned except read write functions, screenshot of which are attached above. And then registers address and all other stuff is given

Comment: @sawdust I had exchanged the pins but that also didn't work. Secondly I didn't get this question " What kind of connection do you have between your "solar inverter" and "RS232 to TTL converter"?

Comment: @Brits the docs you shared are the ones I am using

Comment: @AbrarAliShahas per my first comment, your request is not valid Modbus RTU so I suspect the device will not respond even if the wiring is correct (but the docs are not poor so difficult to be sure!). I'd suggest taking this one step at a time - e.g. connect unit to a PC with RS485 adapter and ensure you can communicate before moving it to ESP32.

Comment: "*I had exchanged the pins but that also didn't work.*" -- That doesn't mean my comments are invalid. Your result simply indicates that you have multiple issues to resolve.

Comment: @Brits I tried to connect RS232 to USB adapter with my Laptop but it had caused my laptop to turn off.

Comment: @sawdust exactly that's what I am trying to point out.

Comment: @Brits I read the data successfully using rs485 through the rs485 port but am facing an issue with rs232. Just clarifying the code is same for rs485 and rs232?